# How do I write a completion handler for firebase data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

So I had issues previously working with 'observe' from firebase, and I realised I could not bring the variable values from inside the code block that was working asynchronously. A user told me to use completion handlers to resolve this issue, and his example was:

```
func mapRegion(completion: (MKCoordinateRegion)->()) {

 databaseHandle = databaseRef.child("RunList").child(runName).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let runData = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
    self.minLat = runData?["startLat"] as? Double
    self.minLng = runData?["startLong"] as? Double
    self.maxLat = runData?["endLat"] as? Double
    self.maxLng = runData?["endLong"] as? Double
    print("testing")
    print(self.minLat!)
    print(self.maxLng!)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (self.minLat! + self.maxLat!)/2,
                                       longitude: (self.minLng! + self.maxLng!)/2),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: (self.maxLat! - self.minLat!)*1.1,
                               longitudeDelta: (self.maxLng! - self.minLng!)*1.1))
    completion(region)

})
}
```

and to use the code:

```
mapRegion() { region in
 mapView.region = region
 // do other things with the region
}
```

So I've tried to recreate this for another method that I need to return an array of object type RunDetail:

```
func loadRuns(completion: ([RunDetail]) -> ()) {

    // we need name, distance, time and user
    databaseHandle = databaseRef.child("RunList").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print(self.count!)

        // more stuff happening here to add data into an object called RunDetail from firebase
        // add RunDetail objects into array called 'run'

    })

    completion(runs)

}
```

I am not sure if I am setting this up correctly above^.

I still cannot get my head around getting the completion handler working (I really don't understand how to set it up). Can someone please help me and let me know if I am setting this up properly? Thanks.

Comment: I fixed up my attempt a bit, forgot to add it in the edit reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the `completion(region)` to inside the Firebase completion block and add `@escaping` after `completion:`.

Also, you should not force unwrap optionals. It is easy enough to check that they are not `nil` and this will prevent the app from crashing.

```
func mapRegion(completion: @escaping (MKCoordinateRegion?) -> Void) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("RunList").child(runName).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard

            let runData = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Double>,

            let minLat = runData["startLat"],

            let minLng = runData["startLong"],

            let maxLat = runData["endLat"],

            let maxLng = runData["endLong"]

        else {

            print("Error! - Incomplete Data")

            completion(nil)

            return
        }

        var region = MKCoordinateRegion()

        region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (minLat + maxLat) / 2, longitude: (minLng + maxLng) / 2)

        region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake((maxLat - minLat) * 1.1, (maxLng - minLng) * 1.1)

        completion(region)
    })
}
```

Then update your code to this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    mapRegion { (region) in

        if let region = region {

            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

For your `loadRuns`

```
func loadRuns(completion: @escaping (Array<RunDetail>) -> Void) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("RunList").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        var runs = Array<RunDetail>()

        // Populate runs array.

        completion(runs) // This line needs to be inside this closure.
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I understood how that example worked as it was an answer from another user. In my question I gave an example of my own attempt to return an array, and that is where I am confused if I am setting up the completion block correctly. Hence, this answer doesn't help me much..

Comment: Okay that makes sense, and I would use 'runs' the same way as the example is given for 'region' in the other example?